# Implementation of Cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I am confused since many individuals have their own approach to apply the cross-validation. For instance, some apply it on the whole dataset and some apply it on the training set.

**My question** is whether the below code is **appropriate** to implement cross-validation and make **predictions** from such model while having **Cross-validation** being applied?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

model= GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators= 10,max_depth = 10, random_state = 0)#sepcifying the model
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

#X -the whole dataset
#y - the whole dataset but target attributes only

y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=cv)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You `need to have a test set` to evaluate performance on completely unseen data even for cross validation. Performance tuning should not be done on this test set to avoid `data leakage`.

Split data into two segments train and test. There are various CV methods such as K-Fold, Stratified K-Fold etc. Visualization and further reading material here,

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

In K-Fold CV training data is split into `K sets`. Then for each fold, `K-1` of the fold is trained and the remaining one is used for performance evaluation.

The image and further detail about cross validation, train/validation/test split etc. can be found here.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

[image]

Visualization of K-Fold cross validation for `3 classes`,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your information, I have updated the code in my question. I am using the whole dataset now, is that the correct approach